# E/StorageUtil( 5389): error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to upload a file to Firebase and it is failing in the following functions in my opinion. If anyone of you has had a similar issue while using Firebase to upload files, I’d appreciate if you could share your solution. Thanks

```
 void uploadFile() async {
    String fileName = basename(sampleFile.path);
    final StorageReference storageFileRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
    var timeKey = new DateTime.now();
    final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageFileRef.child(timeKey.toString() + ".pdf").putFile(sampleFile);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    var FileUrl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    url = FileUrl.toString();
    print("File url = $url");
    saveToDataBase(url);
  }

  void saveToDataBase(String url) {
    var dbTimeKey = new DateTime.now();
    var formatDate = new DateFormat('MMM d, yyyy');
    var formatTime = new DateFormat('EEEE, hh:mm: aaa');

    String date = formatDate.format(dbTimeKey);
    String time = formatTime.format(dbTimeKey);

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    var data = {
      "file" : url,
      "description" : _myValue,
      "date" : date,
      "time" : time,
    };

    ref.child("Reports").push().set(data);

  }
```

I get the following error. I have provided those as well further down. Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
E/StorageUtil( 5389): error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
W/NetworkRequest( 5389): no auth token for request
E/StorageException( 5389): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException( 5389): User does not have permission to access this object.
E/StorageException( 5389):  Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
```

The rules set up in Firebase are shown below and anonymous authentication has been enabled.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

The full output is shown below.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
D/EGL_emulation( 5389): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa44b3440: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa449b370)
I/zygote  ( 5389): Do partial code cache collection, code=60KB, data=43KB
I/zygote  ( 5389): After code cache collection, code=60KB, data=43KB
I/zygote  ( 5389): Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5389): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5389): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5389): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5389): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5389): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5389): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5389): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5389): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5389): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5389): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
I/FilePicker( 5389): Checking permission: android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
D/EGL_emulation( 5389): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa44b2e40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x869a6aa0)
D/FlutterView( 5389): Detaching from a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@cf568df
I/FilePicker( 5389): [SingleFilePick] File URI:content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3D1
E/FilePickerUtils( 5389): Getting for API 19 or abovecontent://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3D1
I/zygote  ( 5389): Do full code cache collection, code=121KB, data=83KB
I/zygote  ( 5389): After code cache collection, code=106KB, data=61KB
E/FilePickerUtils( 5389): Document URI
I/FilePickerUtils( 5389): Caching file from remote/external URI
D/FlutterView( 5389): Attaching to a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@cf568df
D/EGL_emulation( 5389): eglCreateContext: 0xa44b3440: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation( 5389): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa44b3440: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa449b370)
D/EGL_emulation( 5389): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa44b2e40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x869a6aa0)
D/EGL_emulation( 5389): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa44b3440: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa449b370)
E/StorageUtil( 5389): error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
D/NetworkSecurityConfig( 5389): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/NetworkRequest( 5389): no auth token for request
I/zygote  ( 5389): Do partial code cache collection, code=110KB, data=71KB
I/zygote  ( 5389): After code cache collection, code=110KB, data=71KB
I/zygote  ( 5389): Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
E/StorageException( 5389): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException( 5389): User does not have permission to access this object.
E/StorageException( 5389):  Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
E/StorageException( 5389): The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException( 5389): java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException( 5389):  at
```

Comment: I'm guessing this has nothing to do with security rules.  There is something wrong with your code.  Please edit the question to show the specific code that's not working the way you expect.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Can some firebase experts provide insights here please?